# ksh can not grab latest files successfully

Tags: regex, bash

Trying to pull latest 3 files from dir. Seems only certain ones come back.

```
INPUT_FILE_NAME=*.txt

DATADIR=/mypath

LATEST_DATADIR_FILE=`ls -l $DATADIR/$INPUT_FILE_NAME | tail -3 | cut -c94-105`
```

Within this directory lets say there are file names FFile.txt & AFile.txt. The above will only bring the latest files back for FFile.txt even though one of the last files received has a AFile.txt name. How can I get it to bring back the latest files if they start with F or A. I tried incorporating  "[A|F]*.txt" to the input file name with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get it to bring back the latest files if they start with F or A.

You can use:

```
ls -lrt "$DATADIR"/[FA]*.txt | tail -3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `/^(A|F)\w+\.txt/` with `^` which means *start of the string*.

Comment: @anubhava I don't have any idea about it.

Comment: is this answer redundant then @anubhava?

Comment: Your regex is right but not for unix. `ls` needs glob pattern instead of a regex pattern.

Comment: @anubhava al right then!, off to learn "glob" pattern and will delete this :)